# Finding first index of element that matches a condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
var item = list.Where(t => somecondition);
```

I would love to be able to find out the index of the element that was returned, in fact, in my case all I want is an index, so that I can .Skip() into the list by that much.

Is there a way to do this in an IEnumerable? I'd hate to use a `List<T>` for this, but that does have a `FindIndex()` method

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'd need more context, but if you're just getting an index so that you can call `.Skip`, I would recommend taking a look at `.SkipWhile`.

If you do really need the index, I'd suggest writing your own `.IndexOf` extension method.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that he probably wants to use `SkipWhile`, because finding the index and then calling `Skip` enumerates the query twice

Comment: So close ... now I want to use SkipWhile in conjunction with a counter, i.e. list.SkipWhile(myBusinessLogicCondition && list.Count - SkipIndex > someXnumber);

Comment: user494352: It seems like you want to look at Jon's `list.Select().SkipWhile()` answer at the end of his post.

Comment: thanks Gabe, I'm looking @ VStudio, there might be a way to doing this in the SkipWhile itself, seems like an overload of SkipWhile does indeed have an index on it.

Comment: Yes, there is an overload of .SkipWhile that offers you the index. eg: list.SkipWhile((value, index) => myBusinessLogicCondigion(value) && list.Count - index > someXnumber);

It does feels awfully imperative, though :-)

Comment: If you need the index only for the skipping condition then yes, you can use the `SkipWhile` overload that passes an index into your predicate function.

Comment: I think extension method is the best and reusable way to solve this.

Answer (score 71):

If you really just need the first index then count the ones that don't match:

```
var index = list.TakeWhile(t => !someCondition).Count()
```

Comment: What happens if there's no match.  Isn't the result going to be the length of the list?

Comment: Yes that's a great point! Should really validate that index is less than the length of the list if you use the code above

Comment: Depends on the context of usage, I am looking for an index to insert something within the list so returning the length of collection in exactly what I want from TakeWhile()

Answer (score 56):

Sure, it's pretty easy:

```
var index = list.Select((value, index) => new { value, index = index + 1 })
                .Where(pair => SomeCondition(pair.value))
                .Select(pair => pair.index)
                .FirstOrDefault() - 1;
```

That will return the index if it finds anything matching, or -1 otherwise. The +1 and -1 is to get the behaviour for the case where there are no matches. If you knew that there would always be a match, it would be simpler:

```
var index = list.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                .Where(pair => SomeCondition(pair.value))
                .Select(pair => pair.index)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you're happy to get the rest of the list from that point onwards, `SkipWhile` is definitely your friend, as mentioned by Chris. If want the rest of the list *and* the original index, that's easy too:

```
var query = list.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                .SkipWhile(pair => !SomeCondition(pair.value))
```

That will give you a sequence of `{ value, index }` pairs from the first value matching `SomeCondition`.

Comment: It's a shame that `FirstOrDefault` doesn't let you specify the default, huh?

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'm trying to incorporate SkipWhile with an index, rather count to see if I've skipped too much.

Comment: if you cast the index to a nullable, then the resulting FirstOrDefault will be a nullable....new { value, index =(int?) index + 1 })

Comment: Old answer/question I know, but this perfectly shows why Linq is not the correct answer for every problem in the universe.

Comment: See [David's improvement on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57299364/199364).

Answer (score 21):

Ofcourse its possible using IEnumerable...

```
 public static class EnumerableExtension
    {

        public static int FirstIndexMatch<TItem>(this IEnumerable<TItem> items, Func<TItem,bool> matchCondition)
        {
            var index = 0;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if(matchCondition.Invoke(item))
                {
                    return index;
                }
                index++;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1. I normally prefer more linq-y answers like Jon's, but in this case this solution is just so much easier to look at and understand what it does. And as an extension method it can still be *used* in a linq expression. Win-win.

Comment: Using `matchCondition.Invoke(item)` isn't necessary. You can just do `matchCondition(item)`.

Comment: Totally agree with Todd. I'm a big fan of Linq but in this case, just enumerate and increment an index. No Linq sequence calls, no creation of intermediate objects to carry the index. Fast and simple. Keeping the logic of extending IEnumerable you even stay compatible with Linq !

Answer (score 9):

You can project the list items with their indexes first:

```
var item = list.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
               .Where(pair => SomeCondition(pair.Item))
               .Select(result => result.Index);
```

Answer (score 2):

In reference to Jon Skeet's answer, you can use DefaultIfEmpty() before calling FirstOrDefault without adding and subtracting from the index.

```
   var index = list.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                .Where(pair => SomeCondition(pair.value))
                .Select(pair => pair.index).DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Nice find - but .First() should be sufficient, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you have a list as opposed to something like an IEnumerbale or an IQueryable this might be nice ...

```
public static int IndexOf<T>(this IList<T> source, Func<T, bool> condition)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
        if (condition(source[i]))
            return i;

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, This is essentially same as [Manish's much earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4075382/199364), which works on any IEnumerable.