# Search multiple strings in string

Tags: c#, string

In a given string, it is easy to search for the first occurrence of a substring like this:

```
int position = "01234".IndexOf ("23"); // returns 2
```

I want to search for the first occurrence of any of multiple possible strings:

```
var options = new [] {"77", "34", "12"};
int position = "01234".ImaginaryIndexOf (options); // should return 1
```

Such a function does not seem to exist in the .NET framework. Am I missing it?

Edit: To clarify, I am looking for a way that works well even for large inputs and unevenly distributed options. Imagine something similar to

```
var options = new [] {"x", "y"};
new String ('x', 1000*1000).IndexOf (options)
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075340/finding-first-index-of-element-that-matches-a-condition-using-linq
            
            var options = new[] { "77", "34", "12" };
            int position = options.Select((value, index) => new { value, index = index + 1 })
                .Where(pair => "01234".IndexOf(pair.value)>0)
                .Select(pair => pair.index)
                .FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Please see edit to answer below - might supply an answer for the case of such a big string

Comment: Define "works well".  String searching a million character string using a naive algorithm is still absurdly fast because large portions of the string get into the cache.  Set a performance goal and see if the naive implementation meets the goal. It will be difficult to improve upon the naive algorithm.

Comment: I note that you can also be a little clever in a naive algorithm. For example, if a search has already found a hit at position 1000, then you can truncate every subsequent search at position 1000, since any hit after that will not be minimal. That could massively speed up the algorithm if you get lucky and find a hit early on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No built-in method that I'm aware of..

But in order to do so you can iterate all the `options` and for each calculate the `IndexOf`. Then retrieve the minimal that is not `-1` (of "not found"):

```
int position = options.Select(o => "01234".IndexOf(o))
                      .OrderBy(i =>i).FirstOrDefault(i=> i != -1);
```

Or instead of sorting (which is `O(nlogn)`) find minimum (`O(n)`):

```
int position = options.Select(o => "01234".IndexOf(o))
                      .Where(i => i != -1).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).Min();
```

---

As for the edit what you can consider is constructing and array of [suffix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) - the array contains m items where m is the distinct amount of first letters of your `options` words. As a general example:

if options is: `"some", "word", "something", "other"` then you'd construct:

```
    0        1        2...
 +-----------------------+
 |  s    |   w    |   o  |
 +- | ------ | ------ | -+
    o        o        t
    |        |        |
    m        r        h
    |        |        |
    e        d        e
   / \       |        |
  $   t      r        $
      |      |
      ...    $
```

Then you iterate your string and for each letter you check if it is in the array. If not continue to next. If it is then you can deepen in the nested tree and check next letter of string compared to next level in tree. If at the end of the main string you have not reached any of the `$` then no item of `options` is in the text.
Of course you can have the array as a `HashSet<T>` to improve the search of the first letter of a word.

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now. Sadly it has the drawback of reading the string multiple times.

Comment: @mafu: And why is that a problem?

Comment: @mafu - how big is the "01234" string that it is a problem reading it several times? Anything that I can think of is still fine

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like that;

```
var options = new[] { "77", "34", "12" };
var position = options.Select(x => "01234".IndexOf(x))
    .Where(x => x > -1).OrderBy(x => x).DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

You could define a string extension;

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int ImaginaryIndexOf(this string str,IEnumerable<string> options)
    {
        return options.Select(x => str.IndexOf(x))
            .Where(x => x > -1).OrderBy(x => x)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(-1).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Then;

```
var options = new[] { "77", "34", "12" };
"01234".ImaginaryIndexOf(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi we can solve this by using for loop or by using regex.Try this following code I used for loop to find index of the first occurrence of a string.

```
var options = new[] { "77", "34", "12" };
        for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(options[i].ToString); 
            int p
```

```html
var options = new[] { "77", "34", "12" };
for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
{

  int position = "770123473673412".IndexOf(options[i].ToString()); 
  MessageBox.Show(position.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy with some LINQ. The tricky part is handling the -1... but if you understand unsigned and signed integers you can make this problem go away with a cast.

```
static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int ImaginaryIndexOf(this string input, IEnumerable<string> searchFor)
    {
        return (int)searchFor
            .Select
            (
                s => (uint)input.IndexOf(s) 
            )
            .Min();
    }
}
```

[Try it out on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JWhMyj).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can use `Regex`

```
string input = "01234";
var rgex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(77|34|12)");
var match = rgex.Match(input);
int position = match.Success ? match.Index : -1;
```

Answer (score -3):

Hi we can solve this by using for loop or by using regex.Try this following code I used for loop to find index of the first occurrence of a string.

```html
var options = new[] { "77", "34", "12" };
for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
{

  int position = "770123473673412".IndexOf(options[i].ToString()); 
  MessageBox.Show(position.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Do not post same answer twice